# SQLite: Get rid of , and () while printing Python

Tags: python, sqlite

I have created a database in sqlite which looks like this

```
employeeID    Name      Last    email                Age
1             Darshan   Malu    darshan@example.com  24
2             Anja      Schmidt anja@example.com     22
3             Neeta     Rajan   neeta@gmail.com      28
4             Michelle  Muller  m@gmail.com          32
```

So for enquiring by searching for ID I use this code using input as first and last name

```
c.execute("SELECT employeeID FROM employee WHERE first=:first AND last=:last",{"first":first,"last":last})
print('Your Employee ID is', c.fetchone())
conn.close
```

Which does it work.

It returns me "Your Employee ID is (1,)"

So question is

1. Why is there a ',' after the ID
2. How to get rid of both , and ()? so that it just prints out "Your Employee ID is 1"

Comment: Because queries always return _tuples_ of results. Just `print(c.fetchone()[0])`. Also, not that `conn.close` does not close the connection because you didn't call the method

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked. Can you please write this as answer so that I would mark the question as solved

Comment: I'm currently trying to find a dupe because this is a common issue. If someone else wants to answer, fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to fetch the results. `featchall()` will return a list of tuple like `[(1,)]`, and `fetchone()` will return only the first value of the list which is `(1,)` so if you just want to get 1 you need to use call `fetchone()[0]`.

And, `conn.close()` not just `conn.close`

For inserting or deleting call this:

```py
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```